# How to write comments for function in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

```
<?php

class Hello
{
    public function hello()
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I have function and I need to give comments and write documents for the same, like `@param`, `@return`.

How can I do that?

I am very new to PhpStorm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking about is called **PHPDoc**: [PSR-5: PHPDoc](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md).

Comment: If you place your caret the line above the code block you want to describe (class, method, property, etc.) and type `/**` then hit __Enter__, your IDE will try to generate the comment block for you. Try it.

Answer (score 5):

1) Place the caret before the required code construct (class, method, function, and so on), type the opening block comment `/**`, and `press Enter`.

2) In the editor context menu, select `Generate | Generate PHPDoc blocks` and choose the code construct to generate PHPDoc comments for.

3) Press `Alt+Insert`, then select `Generate PHPDoc blocks`, and choose the code construct to 
 generate PHPDoc comments for.

You can check this link for more info.: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/phpdoc-comments.html